# Handlebars - You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile not working

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Good Day,

I am trying to create a handlebars demo using an external precompiled file.  Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Handlebars Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hello Handlebars!</h2>

<!--Your new content will be displayed in here-->
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>

<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/first.js"></script>
<script src="js/finished/first.tpl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // Grab the template script
    var theTemplateScript = $("#address-template").html();

    // Compile the template
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

    // Define our data object
    var context={
        "city": "London",
        "street": "Baker Street",
        "number": "221B"
    };

    // Pass our data to the template
    var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context);

    // Add the compiled html to the page
    $('.content-placeholder').html(theCompiledHtml);
});
```

Here's my first.hbs

```
<!--This is our template. -->
<!--Data will be inserted in its according place, replacing the brackets.-->
<script id="address-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>You can find me in {{city}}. My address is {{number}} {{street}}.</p>
</script>
```

I compiled first.hbs this way:

handlebars templates/first.jbs -f finished/first.tpl.js

and my file structure (where my javascript libraries reside in components):

```
+ HandlebarsDemo
    + components
    + js
        + finished
            + first.tpl.js
        + templates
            + first.jbs
      first.js
  index.html
```

I looked at the following:  [Handlebars Pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354102/handlebars-pass-a-string-or-handlebars-ast-to-handlebars-compile)

I understand that I need to have the Handlebars.compile() before theTemplateScript is loaded into the DOM, so I moved my javascript code to the bottom and am still getting this error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

TIA,

coson

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer on the question you linked to, you need to have the template script in the DOM *before* you try to compile it. If you set a breakpoint in the debugger I'd be willing to bet you're passing `null` to the function (as a result of calling `document.getElementById` on an incomplete DOM).